# Why am I getting "Candidate constructor not viable"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Node1 {
    unsigned int vertex;
    unsigned int representative;
    Node1(unsigned int Vert, unsigned int Rep) : vertex(Vert), representative(Rep) {}
};

class Graph{
    vector<Node1> nodes;
public:

    void findComponents() {
        nodes.emplace_back(1, 1);
        nodes.resize(1);
//        nodes.resize(newSize);
    }
};

int main(){
    Graph g;
    g.findComponents();
}
```

I'm getting a ton of weird build errors mainly consisting of "Candidate constructor not viable" and " In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector >::resize' requested her"

Comment: `std::vector::resize()` requires a default constructor.

Comment: Why do you even need `nodes.resize(1)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what kind of default constructor should I write?

Comment: @rustyx I pruned away a lot of other code. I'm doing a unique(vector) and I need to resize

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ for resize default constructor, what does it need to do?

Comment: @Bob Only thing I can tell you is you'll need something like `Node1() = default;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but what kind of default do I need for .size()? I can make default member variables anything?

Comment: changing the existing constructor to `Node1(unsigned int Vert = 0, unsigned int Rep = 0)` ...  would fix it

Comment: the code that's actually in the question makes no sense: if the vector is empty and you call `emplace_back`, then `resize(1)` would have no effect since the size is already 1.  But if the vector was not empty then `resize(1)` will discard  the element you just emplaced

Comment: @M.M ah that's fantastic to know. Didn't know the ability of default values in constructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the below overload of [`vector::resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) which you are using in your code, `T` must meet the requirements of MoveInsertable and DefaultInsertable.

```
void resize( size_type count );
```

DefaultInsertable means that an instance of the type can be **default-constructed in-place**.

So what you need is a default constructor for `Node1`. For that you can do this:

```
Node1() = default;
```

Or specify default values for `Vert` and `Rep` in the existing constructor like this:

```
Node1(unsigned int Vert = 0, unsigned int Rep = 0) : vertex(Vert), representative(Rep) {}
```